# Consolidating text running python subprocess with IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, console, subprocess, python-idle

So I currently have a python script running four webscraping tools (which all work, that's not the question):

```
    subprocess.run(['python', 'webscraping_pokebattlertopraidcounters.py'])
    subprocess.run(['python', 'webscraping_pvpoke.py'])
    subprocess.run(['python', 'savegbllimitedmetas.py'])
    subprocess.run(['python', 'webscraping_movetypes.py'])
```

When the console is open I get something along the lines of this (below is just a sample):

```
[1210/083450.940:INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "viewportSize     (&vp)   779x579", source:https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js (22)
[1210/083450.941:INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)", source: https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js (22)
```

The issue is that I have print statements in the python scripts that let me track progress but get swallowed up by the INFO:CONSOLE text instead of the print statements going to the Python IDLE shell interface. My question is: Is there a way to suppress this INFO:CONSOLE output so I can see these statements? If not, is there a way to direct my print statements to the IDLE shell interface?